# Spring Boot Rest. BasicAuthentication and ErrorController implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

In order to get rid of a WhiteLabel error page I have implemented a CustomErrorController:

```
@RestController
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

private static final String PATH = "/error";
private final CustomErrorAttributes customErrorAttributes;

@Value("${debug}")
private boolean debug;

@Autowired
public CustomErrorController(CustomErrorAttributes customErrorAttributes) {
    this.customErrorAttributes = customErrorAttributes;
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return PATH;
}

@RequestMapping(value = PATH)
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
    Map<String, Object> map = customErrorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, debug);
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(map);
}
```

}

But such a configuration ruined my Basic Authentication implementation. Instead of being presented with a login/password popup I got following with every request I make:

```
{
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "status": 401,
    "timestamp": 1513332317263
}
```

How can I keep an error only for incorrect request?
My `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configure method looks like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have made every page require authentication. You wont want your login page to require authentication as you are not authenticated the first time you visit it.  Also you wont want authentication on error pages so you need to do something like:.antMatchers("/login**").permitAll().antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()

Comment: Thanks @karen. Since this is just a rest api there is no dedicated login page. Your solution didn't work.